# How can I check if there's a record in my collection that matches a criteria?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of Book objects called book. The Book class has a field called Title.

Is there an easy way using Linq (or other) to find out if that collection has a Book object with a title of "Harry"?

Comment: Field or property? Be clear of the difference between the two.

Comment: @BoltClock while there is a difference between fields and properties, and care might need to be given, in this particular case, there won't be a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method for this:

```
book.Any(b => string.Equals(b.Title, "Harry"));
```

This will go through your `book` collection until it finds a book with the Title "Harry" or the end of your collection. If it finds a book with the correct title it stops going through your collection and returns true. If it reaches the end of your collection it returns false.

**Edit:** Please note, this does a [culture-insensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx) equality check. You might want to do a [culture-sensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) one instead depending on your use-case.

Comment: b.Title.Equals is a little dangerous if Title is null.. Should it be book.Any(b => string.Equals(b.Title, "Harry"))

Comment: And also beware if any of the items in the list are null. That could happen too.

Comment: I tried this but got the following message: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Storage.Models.Book>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Storage.Models.Book>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add a using directive for LINQ: `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

To build on what @J.Kommer said, the culture-sensitive check would look something like this:

```
book.Any(b => string.Compare(b.Title, "Harry", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
  CompareOptions.None) == 0);
```